# Manager for auth.Users Proxy model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have the following model which is a proxy of auth.models.User, I need to filter active users in admin interface, so I inherit auth.models.UserManager and made a new Manager.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.contrib import auth


class UserProxyManager(auth.models.UserManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UserProxyManager,self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

@python_2_unicode_compatible    
class UserProxy(auth.models.User):    
    objects = UserProxyManager
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name_plural = 'my_users'
        verbose_name = 'my_user'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

Now I run django shell and test it and get the error:

```
python manage.py shell

>>> UserProxy.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'm using django 1.8.4 and python 3.4

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objects` should be an instance of the Manager, not the class itself.

```
objects = UserProxyManager()
```